# SingleTap ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, touch, gesture

I'm using the gesture in a imageview, I have already implemented the functions of double tap and pinch zoom on the image and work, but I have to overwrite the single touch to pass parameters to an activity.

I wish that I would return the coordinates of the touch on the image and not to the container of the image, especially when I zoom and / or move the picture and touch the same point, I would like you to come back, more or less, the same point, because associated with the image.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
    private class GestureListener extends
        GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

        float x = e.getRawX();
        float y = e.getRawY();
```

x and y are relative to the container and not to the image

Comment: dont use raw x/y, use getX/Y

Comment: is the same, It doesn't take the position on the image, but relative to the container

Comment: use getX/Y and map this point using reverted Matrix: ImageView.getImageMatrix()